# Conditional testing withing a NightWatchJS test script

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I am trying to write a nightwatch test script with conditions in the test script. My code so far

```
module.exports = {
tags: ['getting-started'],
set_url: function (browser) {
browser.url('http://www.google.com');
browser.pause(5000);
browser.assert.title('Google');
if (browser.expect.element('#main').to.be.present) {
    browser.pause(5000);
    browser.setValue('input[type=text]', ['Night Watcher', browser.Keys.ENTER]);
    browser.pause(5000);
    if(browser.assert.containsText('#main', 'The Night Watch')){
    console.log('search has the right result'); // for example
    }else{
    console.log('No result found');
    }
}
browser.end();
}
```

}
But the `browser.expect.element('#main').to.be.present` and `browser.assert.containsText('#main', 'The Night Watch')` returns an object and is not actually the result I am interested with.
But the `browser.expect.element('#main').to.be.present` and `browser.assert.containsText('#main', 'The Night Watch')` returns an object and is not actually the result I am interested with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using page objects...If you don't use page objects then just say browser.elements.  The following solution worked for me

```
      .waitForElementPresent('#main', 1000)
  .api.elements('css selector','input[type=text]',function(result){
    console.log("123");
    if(result.value) {
      console.log("======================================");
      this.setValue('input[type=text]', ['Night Watcher', this.Keys.ENTER]);
      }
  })
  .waitForElementPresent('#main', 1000, function(res) {
    if(res.value) {
      console.log('search has the right result');
    }else{
        console.log('No result found');
        }
  })
```

Following was the output that I got from the code.. Hope this helps you.. The code could be more optimized though.

[image: OutPut Shown]

## Heading

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic :

```
module.exports = {
    tags: ['getting-started'],
    set_url: function(browser) {
        browser.url('http://www.google.com')
            .pause(5000)
            .assert.title('Google')
            .waitForElementPresent('#main', 3000, function(result) {
                if (result.value === true) { // '#main is present
                    this
                        .setValue('input[type=text)', 'Night Watcher')
                        .click('#search') //instead of enter, you can click search button
                        .getText("#main", function(result) {
                            console.log(result.value);
                            // You can continue here
                        });
                }
            })
            .end();
    }
};
```